# How accessible is YouTube embed in 2013?

Tags: youtube, embed, accessibility

I've got a site I built about 5 years ago which includes video. At the time, we decided that YouTube wasn't accesible enough so went with JW Player. All of their content is now Flash video, and we're looking to make it work on iOS etc.

An easy solution would be to move everything to YouTube (and that would have the advantage of more visibility online), so I'm wondering: how accessible is an embedded YouTube video these days? Is the new HTML5 iframe embed more or less accessible? I can find lots of posts from a few years back saying how unaccessible it is, but not much from the last few years. On this site there won't be any CC - there's a separate transcript available - so it really just needs to be controllable on a basic level via keyboard/screen reader.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: works on a plethora of devices. i would use it.

Comment: Thanks Nathan. But do you mean it's good with keyboard-only users/screen readers now? Or just that it works well on tablets/phones?

Comment: it works on all but you have to use the regular browser on nooks and kindles (at least the nook doesn't have a separate app, not sure on the kindle). actually i have an older nook as well, pretty sure the newer ones work even better. it ought to work on anything that can view videos.

Comment: Just wondering how much of an issue this is in 2015? Anyone know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iframe is fairly accessible, although youtube docs aren't very informative. if you want to go down the rabbit hole, you can read these emails: http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/w3c-wai-ig/2012JanMar/0234.html

iframe embed spec details here: http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/www.google.com/en/us/events/io/2011/static/presofiles/youtube_iframe_player_the_future_of_embedding.pdf

more details: http://polylearnsupport.calpoly.edu/About/YouTubeAccessibility.html
there is still the keyboard problem with flash, although if the users is in a browser that supports html5, that's not a problem anymore. actually, i think the user has to opt-in for html5. or you can roll your own: http://icant.co.uk/easy-youtube/docs/index.html

seems like its fairly good, and is a viable option. of course, you could always upload a video and test it yourself.

Comment: Thanks Albert - that's really useful! For some reason I was finding it hard to find up-to-date info on google. Much appreciated.

Comment: don't worry about it...they are spread about. there's very little under google.com/products/accessibility   the google io slides explaining the iframe embed technology are actually really in depth. i went back through them after i posted. i think you'll be ok. but if not, there are even more add-ons you can roll into your own.

Comment: Thanks again - going to go with the default one for now I think.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not very good, but here's an older review from 2011 - http://terrillthompson.com/blog/44 - not sure how much has changed.

The iframe is just one piece of the challenge.